# spring jpa property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto not working for custom DB configuration in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

in spring boot project, using custom DB configuration. One method is there where adding all properties in map. SQL Server DB

```
protected Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
    HashMap<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "validate");
    jpaProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "validate");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
    jpaProperties.put("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", "false");
    return jpaProperties;
}
```

envers & those properties are working

"`spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete`" for this adding "`org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete`"
but, when adding "`hibernate.ddl-auto`", it is not validating schema.
Tried both "hibernate.ddl-auto" & "`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`".

Read some stack overflow questions, saw most are telling to add "`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`", that is giving validating error, but for proper table also it is giving error

Tried adding "`spring.jpa.generate-ddl`" with value "true" too.

that means properties are getting used for custom db, only the ddl-auto one is not working.
Anything wrong in this?